# EF 6 - Add/update record in table coding pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have written the following code to `Add If does not exist` or `Update if exist` student record in the table.

I am using `Entity Framework 6.1.1` version.

It works for me but i feel it is very basic level code.
Is there any better way i can re-write it please?

**Code:**

```
public void Update(Student student)
{
Student student = _context.Student.Find(studentId);
Student orignal = new Student { Id = student.Id, RollNumber = student.RollNumber, StudentType = student.StudentType, Class = student.Class};

using (var context = new DBContext())
    {
        if (student != null)
        {
            context.Entry(orignal).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else {
            context.Student.Add(orignal);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `AddOrUpdate` method at namespace System.Data.Entity.Migrations.

```
public void AddOrUpdate(Student student)
{
    using (var context = new DBContext())
    {
        context.Student.AddOrUpdate(student);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that method is best reserved for migrations. Take care with the AddOrUpdate method: http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/

Comment: @ Colin, thank.. I can understand the risk but i think it wont be an issue for me since i'll have only one record to be modified always.